# how to iterate json array in kendo mvc grid

Tags: json, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, grid

i using ajax for reading data from my controller(ShiftReports).and i also using view model for combine two tables.
i don't now how to binding or iterate json array to kendo column.

this is my kendo mvc grid

```
     @(Html.Kendo().Grid<PLIMO.ViewModel.MainEqpViewModel>()
                .Name("MainEQP")
                .DataSource(ds => ds
                    .Ajax()
                    .Read(read => read.Action("Eqp_Read", "ShiftReports"))
                )
                .Pageable()
                .Sortable()
                )
```

this is my controller

```
    public ActionResult Eqp_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            try {
                using (var db = new DBContext())
                {
                    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                    var eqp = new MainEqpViewModel()
                    {
                        Tags = db.Tags.ToList(),
                    };

                    DataSourceResult result = new List<MainEqpViewModel>() { eqp }.ToDataSourceResult(request);

                    return Json(result);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you want to return a list of tags to the kendo grid?

Comment: You need a dynamic column. please refer the sample code https://dotnetlearningarray.blogspot.com/2015/06/telerik-mvc-grid-with-dynamic-columns.html

Answer (score 0):

You need a dynamic column. please refer the sample code https://dotnetlearningarray.blogspot.com/2015/06/telerik-mvc-grid-with-dynamic-columns.html